# I am a tutor and my client does not pay

Tags: money

Client did not pay for first session even though we agreed on paying weekly, now there is second session tomorrow I sent him a message asking about how he would do the payments, he saw it but keeps ignoring. Let's say he did not pay tomorrow either, I have text messages showing that he agrees to pay certain amount, text messages also includes stuff like ''We just finished the session'' etc. What happens if I go to police?

Comment: The police do **not** handle payment matters. You would have to sue in civil court.

Answer (score 2):

If the client is behind in payments, you don't do further sessions until they have caught up. At the moment, the client owes for one session. Tomorrow, they've doubled that if they don't pay. Never have more money at risk than you're prepared to lose.

Your first order of business tomorrow is to ask for payment BEFORE the session.